# Guidance on using the WITH clause in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, common-table-expression

I understand how to use the `WITH` clause for recursive queries (!!), but I'm having problems understanding its general use / power.

For example the following query updates one record whose id is determined by using a subquery returning the id of the first record by timestamp:

```
update global.prospect psp
set    status=status||'*'
where  psp.psp_id=(
           select  p2.psp_id
           from    global.prospect p2
           where   p2.status='new' or p2.status='reset'
           order   by p2.request_ts
           limit   1 )
returning psp.*;
```

Would this be a good candidate for using a `WITH` wrapper instead of the relatively ugly sub-query? If so, why?

Comment: According to the documentation, using `WITH [RECURSIVE]` above `INSERT` and `UPDATE` statements was added in PostgreSQL 9.1.

Comment: @JoeyAdams - using with dml - another layer of the onion to understand

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If there can be **concurrent write access** to involved tables, there are race conditions in the following queries. Consider:

- [Postgres UPDATE … LIMIT 1](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/69497/3684)

---

Your example *can* use a CTE (common table expression), but it will give you nothing a subquery couldn't do:

```sql
WITH x AS (
   SELECT  psp_id
   FROM    global.prospect
   WHERE   status IN ('new', 'reset')
   ORDER   BY request_ts
   LIMIT   1
   )
UPDATE global.prospect psp
SET    status = status || '*'
FROM   x
WHERE  psp.psp_id = x.psp_id
RETURNING psp.*;
```

The returned row will be the *updated* version.

---

**If** you want to insert the returned row into another table, that's where a `WITH` clause becomes essential:

```sql
WITH x AS (
   SELECT  psp_id
   FROM    global.prospect
   WHERE   status IN ('new', 'reset')
   ORDER   BY request_ts
   LIMIT   1
   )
, y AS (
   UPDATE global.prospect psp
   SET    status = status || '*'
   FROM   x
   WHERE  psp.psp_id = x.psp_id
   RETURNING psp.*
   )
INSERT INTO z
SELECT *
FROM   y;
```

Data-modifying queries using CTEs were added with PostgreSQL 9.1.
[The manual about `WITH` queries (CTEs).](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html)

Comment: wow - really good - thanks.  agree with quality of pg doc, but to date CTE's have been one of those things that sound cool when I read about it, but in practice have never had a handle on it.  your two example (I think!) have helps a lot

Answer (score 10):

`WITH` lets you define "temporary tables" for use in a `SELECT` query.  For example, I recently wrote a query like this, to calculate changes between two sets:

```
-- Let o be the set of old things, and n be the set of new things.
WITH o AS (SELECT * FROM things(OLD)),
     n AS (SELECT * FROM things(NEW))

-- Select both the set of things whose value changed,
-- and the set of things in the old set but not in the new set.
SELECT o.key, n.value
    FROM o
    LEFT JOIN n ON o.key = n.key
    WHERE o.value IS DISTINCT FROM n.value

UNION ALL

-- Select the set of things in the new set but not in the old set.
SELECT n.key, n.value
    FROM o
    RIGHT JOIN n ON o.key = n.key
    WHERE o.key IS NULL;
```

By defining the "tables" `o` and `n` at the top, I was able to avoid repeating the expressions `things(OLD)` and `things(NEW)`.

Sure, we could probably eliminate the `UNION ALL` using a `FULL JOIN`, but I wasn't able to do that in my particular case.

---

If I understand your query correctly, it does this:

- Find the oldest row in global.prospect whose status is 'new' or 'reset'.
- Mark it by adding an asterisk to its status
- Return the row (including our tweak to `status`).

I don't think `WITH` will simplify anything in your case.  It may be slightly more elegant to use a `FROM` clause, though:

```
update global.prospect psp
set    status = status || '*'
from   ( select psp_id
         from   global.prospect
         where  status = 'new' or status = 'reset'
         order  by request_ts
         limit  1
       ) p2
where  psp.psp_id = p2.psp_id
returning psp.*;
```

<sub>Untested.  Let me know if it works.</sub>

It's pretty much exactly what you have already, except:

- This can be easily extended to update multiple rows.  In your version, which uses a subquery expression, the query would fail if the subquery were changed to yield multiple rows.
- I did not alias `global.prospect` in the subquery, so it's a bit easier to read.  Since this uses a `FROM` clause, you'll get an error if you accidentally reference the table being updated.
- In your version, the subquery expression is encountered for every single item.  Although PostgreSQL should optimize this and only evaluate the expression once, this optimization will go away if you accidentally reference a column in `psp` or add a volatile expression.

Comment: To update multiple rows, one would not need any form of subquery or CTE, just: `UPDATE global.prospect SET status = status || '*'
WHERE status IN ('new', 'reset') RETURNING *;`