# Get default serial value after INSERT inside PL/pgSQL

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, sql-insert, sql-returning, nextval

I have a table. I wrote a function in plpgsql that inserts a row into this table:

```
INSERT INTO simpleTalbe (name,money) values('momo',1000) ;
```

This table has `serial` field called `id`. I want in the function after I insert the row to know the id that the new row received.

I thought to use:

```
select nextval('serial');
```

before the insert, is there a better solution?

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-insert.html Look at the bottom for `insert returning`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [`RETURNING`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html) clause.
And assign the result inside PL/pgSQL with an appended [`INTO`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-ONEROW).

```
INSERT INTO simpleTalbe (name,money) values('momo',1000)
RETURNING id
INTO _my_id_variable;
```

`_my_id_variable` must have been declared with a matching data type.

Related:

- [PostgreSQL next value of the sequences?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13393604/postgresql-next-value-of-the-sequences/13394177#13394177)

Depending on what you plan to do with it, there is often a better solution with pure SQL. Examples:

- [Combining INSERT statements in a data-modifying CTE with a CASE expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28992241/combining-insert-statements-in-a-data-modifying-cte-with-a-case-expression/28993466#28993466)
- [PostgreSQL multi INSERT...RETURNING with multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22775109/postgresql-multi-insert-returning-with-multiple-columns/22775268#22775268)

Answer (score 1):

`select nextval('serial');` would not do what you want; `nextval()` actually increments the sequence, and then the `INSERT` would increment it *again.* (Also, 'serial' is *not* the name of the sequence your `serial` column uses.)

@Erwin's answer (`INSERT ... RETURNING`) is the best answer, as the syntax was introduced specifically for this situation, but you could also do a

```
SELECT currval('simpletalbe_id_seq') INTO ...
```

any time *after* your `INSERT` to retrieve the current value of the sequence. (Note the sequence name format *tablename*_*columnname*_seq for the automatically-defined sequence backing the `serial` column.)