# Running A FOREACH after a CTE in a PostgreSQL procedure?

Tags: postgresql

I have a PLPGSQL procedure that:

A) Inserts an employee into an `Employee` table.
B) Also insert the generated serial `eid` into another `Manager` table.
C) Finally, the procedure also dictates an array of `course_areas` that I would like to insert in a `specialize` table.

**Procedure where C and D array are the course_areas**

```
CALL add_employee('Athena', '22222222', 'athena@outlook.com', '2012-12-12', '111', 'instructor', 300.0, NULL, 
'{C,D}'::text[]);
```

**Employees**

```
CREATE TABLE Employees (
    eid SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name TEXT NOT NULL,
    phone TEXT NOT NULL,
    email TEXT NOT NULL,
    join_date DATE NOT NULL,
    address TEXT NOT NULL,
    depart_date DATE
);
```

**Managers**

```
CREATE TABLE Managers (
    eid INT PRIMARY KEY,
    monthly_salary DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (eid) REFERENCES Employees(eid)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

**Specializes**

```
CREATE TABLE Specializes (
    eid INT NOT NULL,
    name TEXT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (eid, name),
    FOREIGN KEY (eid) REFERENCES Employees(eid)
        on DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (name) REFERENCES Course_areas(name)
        on DELETE CASCADE
);
```

**procedure.sql**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE add_employee (name TEXT, phone TEXT, email TEXT, joinDate DATE, address TEXT, category TEXT, monthlySalary DECIMAL(10,2) default NULL, hourlySalary DECIMAL(10,2) default NULL, courseAreas TEXT[] default NULL)
...

WITH FIRST AS (
  INSERT INTO Employees(
    name, phone, email, join_date, address
  ) 
  VALUES 
    (
      name, phone, email, joinDate, address
    ) RETURNING eid
), 
SECOND AS (
  INSERT INTO Full_time_instructors(eid, monthly_salary) 
  SELECT 
    eid, 
    monthlySalary 
  FROM 
    ROWS RETURNING eid
) 
FOREACH area IN ARRAY courseAreas 
  LOOP 
    RAISE NOTICE '%', area; -- should print "C" and "D"
  END LOOP;
```

**Error**

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "FOREACH"
LINE 27:         FOREACH area IN ARRAY courseAreas
```

I can get A) and B) to work.

How can I use `FOREACH` to iterate through my `courseAreas` that I pass to the procedure such that I can insert each course area and the `eid` into a `Specialize` table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `FOREACH` is a PLPGSQL control structure whereas the CTE is a SQL feature. You can't mix these. Instead of using CTE you can simply perform the first statement, using the `RETURNING` clause to retrieve the `eid` to a local variable. You can then use this variable with the subsequent statement and inside your `FOREACH` loop.

This question gives an overview of getting the new serial value using returning: [Get default serial value after INSERT inside PL/pgSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33837643/get-default-serial-value-after-insert-inside-pl-pgsql).