# "ERROR: query has no destination for result data" for function with INSERT

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I have to create `plpgsql` function for generation `sequence` number considering some `doc_id` argument. I wrote a function, but when I run it I get error

```
[42601] ERROR: query has no destination for result data 
Where: PL/pgSQL function create_sequence_number(text) line 3 at SQL statement
```

My idea: the function gets the `doc_id`, saves or updates the existing entry, returns the value of `sequence`:

```sql
create or replace function create_sequence_number(doc_id TEXT, OUT _result BIGINT) RETURNS BIGINT AS
$$
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO _generated_sequences AS t (id, sequence)
    VALUES (CONCAT('document_sequence_', doc_id), 1)
    ON CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE
        SET sequence = t.sequence + 1
    RETURNING _result = sequence;
END
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

Now my function inserts `sequence` = `1` everywhere. I did it temporarily to solve the error mentioned above, in fact the function should save `1` only for new entries. For existing ones, the already existing `sequence` value should be increased by `1`. But, as far as I know, it is not possible to use `sequence + 1` like in this example:

```sql
INSERT INTO _generated_sequences AS t (id, sequence)
VALUES (CONCAT('document_sequence_', doc_id), sequence + 1)
ON CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE
   SET sequence = t.sequence + 1
RETURNING _result = sequence;
```

```
[42703] ERROR: column "sequence" does not exist 
There is a column named "sequence" in table "t", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query. 
PL/pgSQL function create_document_sequence_number(text) line 3 at SQL statement
```

Comment: `RETURNING _result = sequence` in incorrect syntax. It should be `RETURNING sequence INTO _result`.

Comment: But unfortunately my problem with value for `sequence` still there is. If I write `VALUES (CONCAT('document_sequence_', chat_id), EXCLUDED.sequence + 1)` it does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Laurenz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6464308/laurenz-albe) already pointed out the immediate syntax issue. You must use the keyword `INTO`. See:

- [Get default serial value after INSERT inside PL/pgSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33837643/get-default-serial-value-after-insert-inside-pl-pgsql/33837685#33837685)

But don't use the [solution in your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76836239/939860). It is more expensive than necessary and, more importantly, breaks under concurrent load. The `SELECT` happens while the row is not locked yet. Multiple concurrent transactions might work off the same (outdated) state this way and return the same sequence number.

Also, `sequence_value + 1` is noise for `INSERT`, which must insert `1` in any case. Only `UPDATE` increments the value.

This should work:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pg_temp.create_sequence_number(doc_id text, OUT _result bigint)
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO _generated_sequences AS t
          (id                                  , sequence)
   VALUES (concat('document_sequence_', doc_id), 1       )
   ON     CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE
   SET    sequence = t.sequence + 1
   RETURNING t.sequence
   INTO  _result;  -- INTO instead of "="
END
$func$;
```

The `RETURNS` clause is optional in combination with `OUT` parameters. See:

- [Can I make a plpgsql function return an integer without using a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8169676/can-i-make-a-plpgsql-function-return-an-integer-without-using-a-variable/8169928#8169928)

But a plain SQL function is simpler for this. Then you also don't need `INTO` to begin with:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pg_temp.create_sequence_number(doc_id text)
  RETURNS bigint
  LANGUAGE sql AS
$func$
INSERT INTO _generated_sequences AS t
       (id                                  , sequence)
VALUES (concat('document_sequence_', doc_id), 1       )
ON     CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE
SET    sequence = t.sequence + 1
RETURNING sequence;
$func$;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed explanation. Now everything is much clearer

Answer (score 0):

Function that works for me in result:

```
create or replace function create_sequence_number(doc_id TEXT, OUT _result BIGINT) RETURNS BIGINT AS
$$
DECLARE
    sequence_value BIGINT;
    sequence_id TEXT;
BEGIN
    sequence_id = (CONCAT('document_sequence_', doc_id));
    sequence_value = (SELECT coalesce((select sequence from _generated_sequences where id = sequence_id), 0));

    INSERT INTO _generated_sequences AS t (id, sequence)
    VALUES (sequence_id, sequence_value + 1)
    ON CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE
        SET sequence = t.sequence + 1
    RETURNING sequence into _result;
END
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```